# How do I prevent constantly having to upgrade packages in Unity Package Manager?

Tags: unity-game-engine, jetbrains-ide, rider

I use Rider from JetBrains as my code editor and everytime I create new project in Unity, it asks me to update it to newer version.

I believe that this is explicitly Unity's issue and I think it can happen with any package.

[image: Updates]

How can I prevent this behavior? Is it possible to update packages automatically in the package manager?

I've always updated it to newer version in previous projects but it always asks me to do it again.

Comment: it is a per project setting - unity 6 seems to auto do it, which has its own curses btw

Comment: Can you not just refuse? Keep the older package until it breaks?

Comment: I can use it until it breaks, but you must admit it's pretty annoying opening Rider and seeing the message 'Update the package to newer version' every single time.

Comment: @BugFinder is it per project ? Why is it happening only with Rider tho ?

Comment: probably because the others havent changed version and yes, packages are per project.

Comment: allright, that seems to answer my question.. if Unity 6 will auto do it I'll be happier. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing tho.. where does Unity know to always install version 3.0.26 of Rider and  not 3.0.28 ? or .27 ?

Comment: probably because thats the default one for the version of unity you're installing

Answer (score 0):

According to @BugFinder , packages are per project so until Unity 6 will come out, we have to manually install each update even if we did in previous projects.